# Getting microseconds past the hour

Tags: python, python-2.7, time, real-time

I am working on a quick program to generate DIS (Distributed Interactive Simulation) packets to stress test a gateway we have.  I'm all set and rearing to go, except for one small issue.  I'm having trouble pulling the current microseconds past the top of the hour correctly.

Currently I'm doing it like this:

```
now = dt.now()
minutes = int(now.strftime("%M"))
seconds = int(now.strftime("%S")) + minutes*60
microseconds = int(now.strftime("%f"))+seconds*(10**6)
```

However when I run this multiple times in a row, I'll get results all over the place, with numbers that cannot physically be right.  Can someone sanity check my process??

Thanks very much

Comment: What are these crazy conversions? `datetime` has `minutes`, `seconds` and `microseconds` attributes.

Comment: Output looks fine on my machine. I'd go with @TigerHawkT3's answer though

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can eliminate all that formatting and just do the following:

```
now = dt.now()
microseconds_past_the_hour = now.microsecond + 1000000*(now.minute*60 + now.second)
```

Keep in mind that running this multiple times in a row will continually produce different results, as the current time keeps advancing.